# asp.net: calling asp page while wcf operation is processing

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf

I have a web application consists of several aspx pages + wcf service (one project) and a silverlight app. I have the following problem: I open silverlight app, it does async call to my long wcf service operation. While it is processing I can't request any other aspx page of my site. Why it happens? Is it session locking? I will be grateful for the tip. I can get any non asp page from server (iis6), but any aspx page can be processed only after wcf operation is done.

**EDIT:** I solved it by

> aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your wcf ws is locking a database table also used by other aspx pages.
Are you using synchronization locks ? Serializable transactions ?
Or maybe you have a debugger attached.

Comment: I did the test: if I request aspx which do a call to long wcf operation, I can't request any other aspx in this session until long wcf operation returns. I fix this by EnableSessionState=false. May be something like this happens in the case of silverlight (in my example above). But for now I don't find any reasonable solution.